# Python problem during Bibus installation

Tags: 11.10, python

I cannot install bibus from the application centre. I am a new user of ubuntu and I found it is very helpful. When I was trying to install Bibus, they told me the Package dependencies cannot be resolved:

> bibus: Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.7.2-7ubuntu2 is to be installed.

I tried to install the package manually, but it does not work still.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bibus/+bug/849174

Looks like a workaround is to download from upstream.

http://packages.debian.org/sid/bibus